# Bash how multiple if's work

Tags: bash

Trying to check if the command line parameters is equal to 3 or 5.  If so continue, if not exit.  Can't figure out in bash how the multiple if's works.  So tried (( and [[.  For example:

```
if (( $# != 3 || $# != 5 )); then
  echo 1>&2 "Usage check_snmp_dell <hostname> <itemtocheck> <snmpname> <warning> <critical>"
  exit 3
fi
```

errors that the wrong parameters were used even if I have 3 or 5.

Thoughts?

Thanks.

JR

Comment: Should be: `$# != 3 && $# != 5`

Comment: Note I know if [ $# -ne 3]; then

Comment: works....................

Comment: Thanks.  Guess I don't understand it.  Figured it's an "OR" as I want to check if it's 3 "OR" 5.  Not 3 AND 5.  Obviously works but scratching my head.

Comment: @John That would be true if you were actually check if `$#` equaled 3 or equaled 5, but you are checking if it is *not* equal to 3 or *not* equal to 5. Another way of putting it would be `if ! (( $# == 3 || $# == 5 ))`.

Comment: @John You may find [shellcheck](http://shellcheck.net) useful. It automatically detects [this](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2056) and other issues.

Answer (score 3):

```
$# != 3 || $# != 5
```

This will be true if the number is *either* not 3 *or* not 5, and obviously that is true of any number. What you want is to check that the number is *both* not 3 *and* not 5, which is what the `&&` operator is for:

```
$# != 3 && $# != 5
```

Comment: brilliant thanks.  Guess I'm not thinking well today. :)